# I answered my own question and accepted the answer. Why is it not at the top?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked [a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139603/google-analytics-with-multiple-environments) and it got some answers. But none of them was what I really wanted. After investigating by myself, I found a solution that best fit my needs, so [I answered my own question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/141949/38148) and marked my own answer as the accepted one.

My answer is not the first one at the top. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent gaming the system, self-accepts:

- don't float up the top
- don't award you 15 reputation for the acceptance
- don't award you 2 reputation for accepting an answer

I like to think of it as resolving a conflict of interest: it's assumed you think it's the best answer because you answered it, so the fact that you accepted your own answer is useful information to future visitors.

Comment: I understand that I won't gain any reputation, but that was not my question. If I found the answer myself, I want others to know what was the solution I used to solve my problem.. That's why I think self-accepted answers should be to the top also.

Comment: @marcof And they will, by seeing the check mark next to it. But you have a conflict of interest: it's your answer, so of course you think it's the best. Answers at the top have presumably been vetted by someone independent of the person writing it (either by votes or by the asker not being the answerer). That's not the case with a 0-score self answer. If other people think it's a good answer too, it'll be voted up to the top.

Comment: It's clearer now, thank you!