# What if a wrong answer gets a lot of upvotes?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I answered my own question and accepted the answer. Why is it not at the top?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3376/i-answered-my-own-question-and-accepted-the-answer-why-is-it-not-at-the-top)

I have posted [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140483/is-it-a-waste-of-time-to-free-resources-before-i-exit-a-process/141014) not long ago. And I got some really interesting answers. One got a lot of up votes, but after some investigation, I asked my instructor at the university, and got [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140483/is-it-a-waste-of-time-to-free-resources-before-i-exit-a-process/141014#141014) which actually proves the most up-voted answer wrong. I don't want to down-vote that guy, because he showed an interesting aspect. But I think that my answer should at least appear a little higher, so people at least see it. Because if we're honest, who reads all the answers through and really thinks about them?!

I'm not concerned about other answers because most of them answered about "good software engineering" and not my theoretical question. But they are worth reading.

So my question is actually: why is the accepted answer so low in the thread?

Comment: Martin the answer on the duplicate explains why your answer is not at the top. The only thing we can do is up vote your answer, something that everyone is free to do if they feel the answer is useful. People getting to your question from the question list would know it has an accepted answer and they'll probably scout for the shiny green checkmark (at least I do), but other than that there isn't much we can do. You left a comment to the top voted answer, which also would lead people to your answer. I've edited that and added a direct link to your answer, so it'd be a little easier to find.

Comment: OK thanks. You should write that as an answer :)